# Avada header - Div with responsive SVG line is not overlapping

Tags: html, css, wordpress, svg, header

I'm trying to stylize the Avada header (version 1), by adding some divs to have multiple colors and adding a responsive diagonal SVG line.

I made a div with the diagonal svg line in it, and put it into the header parent div.

But no matter what I try to do, I can't get the div holding the SVG to overlap with the main header div. Instead it posts it above or below. I've tried to put it into every div in the header area; I've messed around with z-index everyway I could think. 
I'm a newbie, but I would love any assistance I could get.  Thanks in advance!

website: www.deccanlaw.com/CLONE4

Here is the html I put in the header.php file:

```
    <div class="fusion-header-sticky-height"></div>
      <div class="fusion-header">
        <div class="DeccanHeader" id="Diagonal1">
           <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"height="100%" width="20%" id=SVGdiagonal>
                <line x1="2%" y1="0%" x2="98%" y2="100%" style="stroke: #b6bbc2;stroke-width:12" />
            </svg>                  
          </div>
        <div class="fusion-row">
            <?php avada_logo(); ?>
            <?php avada_main_menu(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: make it style="position: absolute" Does that do what you want? If not you need to describe what you do want more clearly.